# filter custom field with checkboxes and show it with one shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have a custom field with checkboxes. I created a code to show post-typs filtered by checkbox value with shortcodes e.g. `[bettenaert-Querbett]`. The code works but do not look nice.

```
if ($i = 'Querbett') {
    add_shortcode( "bettenaert-{$i}", function() use ( $i ) {
    modell_nach_bettenart_2( $i );
        } );
}
if ( $i = 'Alkovenbett' ) {
    add_shortcode( "bettenaert-{$i}", function() use ( $i ) {
    modell_nach_bettenart_2( $i );
        } );
}
if ( $i = 'Queensbett') {
    add_shortcode( "bettenaert-{$i}", function() use ( $i ) {
    modell_nach_bettenart_2( $i );
        } );
}
if ( $i = 'Hubbett') {
    add_shortcode( "bettenaert-{$i}", function() use ( $i ) {
    modell_nach_bettenart_2( $i );
        } );
}
```

Is there any way to make the value variable, to have only one if-function or can I do it in an other way? Has anyone an idea and can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( "Querbett", "bettenaert");
add_shortcode( "Alkovenbett", "bettenaert");
add_shortcode( "Queensbett", "bettenaert");
add_shortcode( "Hubbett", "bettenaert");

function bettenaert (  $atts, $content = null, $tag ) {

   modell_nach_bettenart_2( $tag );

}
```

Now use shortcode `[Querbett]`, `[Alkovenbett]`, `[Queensbett]` or`[Hubbett]` as required.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have custom post type called 'womos'. The custom field name is 'bettenart'. And the shordcode should be variable like [Querbett], [Alkovenbett], [Queensbett] and [Hubbett] or something like this. I don't know, if I can realize this with your given code. I have no idea how. Have you any further tip for me?

Comment: OK, got it. Let me update my answer shortly.

Comment: Have look at updated answer. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't no why and how but it works great! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @kuh13  [Check this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/multiple-shortcodes-with-a-single-function-3-killer-examples--wp-30966) for detail.